# how to call an oracle stored procedure in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, oracle, api, stored-procedures

I am new to node.js and have a question as to how to call a stored procedure with in and out parameters.

This is my stored procedure which is taking in and out parameters: Basically I am taking three main parameters

ls_id_order,ln_item_no, ln_part_order

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CRMDBA.C1DVX007 ( ls_id_order IN VARCHAR2,
ln_item_no IN NUMBER,
ln_part_order IN NUMBER,
ln_order_qty OUT NUMBER,
ln_in_proc_qty_hr OUT NUMBER,
ln_procd_hr_mass OUT NUMBER,
ln_in_proc_qty OUT NUMBER,
ln_wip OUT NUMBER,
ln_qa OUT NUMBER,
ln_packing OUT NUMBER,
ln_dispatchable_qty OUT NUMBER,
ln_despatched_qty OUT NUMBER ,
ln_finished_qty OUT NUMBER,
ln_balance_qty OUT NUMBER,
ln_bal_disp_qty OUT NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
ln_in_proc_qty_hr := 0 ;
ln_procd_hr_mass := 0 ;
ln_in_proc_qty := 0 ;
ln_wip := 0 ;
ln_qa := 0 ;
ln_packing := 0 ;
ln_dispatchable_qty := 0 ;
ln_despatched_qty := 0 ;
ln_finished_qty := 0 ;
ln_balance_qty := 0 ;
ln_bal_disp_qty := 0; --CALCULATION OF ORDER QNTY
BEGIN
SELECT por_ms_prt_order
INTO ln_order_qty
FROM v_part_order
WHERE por_wo_no = ls_id_order
AND por_item_no = ln_item_no
AND por_id_part_order = ln_part_order;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END; ----HR AT HSM
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SUM(APP_MS_PIECE_ACT),0)
INTO ln_in_proc_qty_hr
FROM kpofp.t_a_prod_piece@tskcrm_kpois_dbl
WHERE APP_id_order = ls_id_order
AND APP_id_order_item = ln_item_no
AND APP_id_part_order = 1
AND APP_cd_prod_grp = '25'
AND APP_cd_st_piece IN ('AC', 'LN', 'AA', 'HB','HC','IN')
AND APP_cd_company = '1000'
AND APP_cd_dept = '117'
AND APP_id_proc_cntr = '01';
ln_in_proc_qty_hr := ROUND(ln_in_proc_qty_hr);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END; ----HR AT CRM
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SUM(hrc_ms_piece_act),0)
INTO ln_procd_hr_mass
FROM v_hr_coil
WHERE hrc_id_order = ls_id_order
AND hrc_id_order_item = ln_item_no
AND hrc_id_part_order = ln_part_order
AND hrc_cd_st_piece IN ('PB','PC','PJ','PD');
ln_procd_hr_mass:= ROUND(ln_procd_hr_mass);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END; ---INPROCESS QTY CR
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
INTO ln_in_proc_qty
FROM v_cold_coil
WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
AND ccl_cd_status IN ('AB','AC','AJ,''AD','LB','LC','LJ','LD','GB','GC','GJ','GD','RB','RC','RJ','RD','XB','XC','XJ','XD',
'YB','YC','YJ','YD','DB','DC','DJ','DD','PP') ;
ln_in_proc_qty := ROUND(ln_in_proc_qty);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END;----QA AT CRM
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
INTO ln_qa
FROM v_cold_coil
WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
AND (ccl_cd_status LIKE '%Q'
OR ccl_cd_status IN ('AP','LP','GP','RP','XP','YP','DP')) ;
ln_qa := ROUND(ln_qa);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END;----PACKING AT CRM
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
INTO ln_packing
FROM v_cold_coil
WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
AND ccl_cd_status IN ('CB','CC','CJ','CD','CP','TB','TC','TJ','TD','TP','MB','MC','MJ','MD','MP') ;
ln_packing:= ROUND(ln_packing);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END;----DESPATCHABLE AT CRM
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
INTO ln_dispatchable_qty
FROM v_cold_coil
WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
AND ccl_cd_status IN ('VB','VC','VD','VP') ;
ln_dispatchable_qty:= ROUND(ln_dispatchable_qty);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END; ----DESPATCHED AT CRM
BEGIN
SELECT NVL(SUM(ccl_ms_piece_actl),0)
INTO ln_despatched_qty
FROM v_cold_coil
WHERE ccl_id_order = ls_id_order
AND ccl_id_order_item = ln_item_no
AND ccl_id_order_part = ln_part_order
AND ccl_cd_status ='VL';
ln_despatched_qty:= ROUND(ln_despatched_qty);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END;
ln_balance_qty := ( NVL(ln_order_qty,0) - NVL(ln_in_proc_qty_hr,0)- NVL(ln_procd_hr_mass ,0)
- NVL(ln_in_proc_qty,0)-NVL(ln_qa,0)-nvl(ln_packing,0)-NVL(ln_despatched_qty,0)
- NVL(ln_dispatchable_qty,0) ) ;
END;
/
```

I am trying to call that stored procedure in node.js

Normally for a query I would run something like this:

```
export const reasonlist = async () => {
  try {
    const sql =
      "SELECT cd_desc des, cd_value cd FROM v_codes WHERE cd_type='CVS02' order by cd_desc";
    return await query(sql);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error.InternalServerError("Error!");
  }
};
```

How do I call a stored procedure for this I know the process for a query what is the process for a stored procedure?? PLease help

Comment: The node-oracledb documentation [PL/SQL Stored Procedures](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlproc) is the place to start.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a simple stored procedure example so that I can relate

Comment: The link above has the PL/SQL code to create a simple stored procedure and the Node.js code to call it.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
let result = await connection.execute(
  `BEGIN CRMDBA.C1DVX007(
    :ls_id_order,
    :ln_item_no,
    :ln_part_order,
    :ln_order_qty,
    :ln_in_proc_qty_hr, 
    ...
   ); END;`,
         {
            ls_id_order: ..., // 'dir: oracledb.BIND_IN' is default, so can be skipped
            ln_item_no: ..., 
            ln_part_order: ..., 
            ln_order_qty: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
            ln_in_proc_qty_hr: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
            ...
        }
      )

console.log(result.outBinds.ln_in_proc_qty_hr)
```